# How to start contributing to emacs manual

Tags: documentation

Actually I am thinking to contribute to emacs manual, Specially in eshell few sections are empty so. Just need some guidance/resource to refer to write in texinfo

Comment: The texinfo info manual is not that big or complicated. If you don't have it installed locally: https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/

Comment: You can also just post a manual-change suggestion using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Even plain-text suggestions are welcome.